# Where does the following equation for the area of an ellipsoid come from?

Tags: geometry, surfaces, area

I have been reading an old draft that I made a few years ago where I used the following expression for the area of an ellipsoid:

$$A=2 \pi r^2 + \frac{2 \pi \tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{1-r^{-6}})}{r^4 \sqrt{1- r^{-6}}}$$

I considered an ellipsoid defined by two parameters, the height and the radius ($r$). I assume that the volume of the ellipsoid is equal to $4\pi/3$ obtaining $h=1/r^2$. I haven't been able to find this equation anywhere and I forgot to write down the reference where I found it.

Where does this equation come from? How does it relate to the usual formula for the area of an [ellipsoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid.html)?

Comment: As you have only one radius this cannot be an ellipsoid. Maybe you had some fixed ratio between axes that gave you that peculiar result.

Comment: When $ r \rightarrow 1 $ the second part does not vanish ( using L'hospital's rule)

Comment: @Narasimham It shouldn't vanish. It should approach $2 \pi$ as $r \to 1$ and it does: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+arctanh%28x%29%2Fx+x+to+0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from the formula for the surface area of an [oblate spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid) (ie, an ellipsoid formed by spinning an ellipse about its minor axis).
$$S = 2\pi a^2 \left(\;1 + \frac{1-e^2}{e}\;\operatorname{atanh} e \;\right) \qquad\text{where}\qquad e^2 = 1 - \frac{c^2}{a^2}$$
where $a$ is the semi-major axis and $c$ the semi-minor axis.

Specifically, taking $a = r$ and $c = r^{-2}$ (your $h$), we get $e^2 = 1 - r^{-6}$, so that
$$S = 2\pi r^2\left(\; 1 + \frac{\operatorname{atanh} \sqrt{1-r^{-6}}}{r^6\;\sqrt{1 - r^{-6}}}\;\right)$$